# Wp_Query : Filter posts by comparing two meta keys

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Suppose I have two meta keys A and B for wordpress post. I need to get all posts where values of A != B using Wp_Query. I could only find codes to compare multiple keys and then do a AND/OR relation. Any ideas? Thanks

```
$args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 100, 
                'paged' => $page
              )

$data= new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: From which meta key you want to compare

Comment: @PiyushDhanotiya Suppose meta keys names are MetaKey1 and MetaKey2. These are our custom fields we added to products. I need to get all products where value of MetaKey1 != MetaKey2

Comment: If you can't rearrange script logic, looks like you should write custom MySQL query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                    'key' => 'A',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='),
            array(
                    'key' => 'B',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '!=')
            )
);
$data = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: This will only work if we know the possible values of  A and B. But this is not the case. We don't know what value it will be in A and B fields.

Comment: I had to write multiple queries for each combination to do this with WP_Query. Your answer helped me with that. Marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in this way. Get values of both your meta keys and store those values in your variables like ($a , $b respectively), then have a check on those values

```
if($a != $b) {$c = $a;} //If content of a is not of same as b $c contains meta value of a meta key
```

Now comes the query section.

```
  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 100, 
            'paged' => $page'
            'meta_key'     => 'a',
            'meta_value'   => $c,
          )

      $data= new WP_Query( $args );
```

Give it a try it will work for you.

**Note:** `a, b and c` `meta keys` and `variables` are just for example purposes, use your own `meta key` and `meta values` to get results that suits you.